# How to get the text between the given graphical points?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to get the text, which lies between two given graphical points on the current page using Javascript?

Say, it is given two points  `p1=(x1,y1)` and `p2=(x2, y2)`.
How can I get the text which lies between `p1` and `p2` on the current HTML/web page?

My requirement is: When we `mousedown` on a page and move the mouse, it selects the underlying texts. I want to select and get the texts, without actually moving the mouse, but just passing two points.

In other words, I want to fake `getSelection()` with two points.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Here is how a basic selection looks like:

```
function selectNode(node) {  
    var selection, range; 
    if (document.createRange
     && document.defaultView
     && window.getSelection) {
        selection = window.getSelection();
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(node);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    } else if (document.body 
            && document.body.createTextRange) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(node);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

**2.** Here is a [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075304/how-to-modify-the-document-selection-in-javascript)

**3.** Here is how i would do it

- where is the mouse (over which element)
- what is the font size (computed style)
- where is the mouse (offset in the element)
- convert start point to character number
- convert the end point to character number
- select text between start - end

**4.** More about custom selection at [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html)

I hope you've got a solid starting point.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but option 1, doesnt answer my question. It simply gives the text selected,only when i select some text using mouse.
option-2 also not much helpful, it also explains the same thing explained here in option-1.
Option-3: i can find out, over which element the mouse is, using event.target. and also i can find out font-size. But how can i find out 'offset in the element' ?

Comment: you compare mouse position with the edges of the element (getBoundingClientRect). You said you've got two points, right? Sth like TopLeft, BottomRight. Now with font-size the selection becomes a grid, and every cell will be a character.

Comment: wouldn't this fail with variable-width fonts?

Comment: yes, because different letters take different pixel size (say 'i' takes minimum width and say 'Q' takes more pixel-width) it may not work properly. It is also possible that in the same element (say p-paragraph) some text would have one font-size and the remaining different font-size.

Comment: @ganapati I guess JavaScript is short for your requirements. If elementFromPoint is what relates points on screen with DOM elements and you can't do much with it. You'd better try to generate an addon for FireFox and stick to that

Answer (score 0):

it will be difficult. you can start with studying `document.elementFromPoint` and `document.createRange`

Comment: i dont think i can do much (of my requirement ) with document.elementFromPoint,and  document.createRange.
Because, for creating range element i need the exact word/letter from where selection should start. But  document.elementFromPoint,returns the element name as 'body', 'p' or 'text'.