# Cross-Browser way to select text

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection

I have one `p` element, how can I select the text inside using JavaScript that will be cross-browser?

```
<p>Some Text to select</p>
```

I want to select that text (like when you use mousedown and move the cursor) on click. It can be jQuery solution.

Comment: You want [rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/). But I'm afraid "help me find a library" kind of questions are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I don't want to use Rangy, it's so more then 40KB minified. It should be something with few lines of code.

Comment: @PaulS. I want cross-browser solution.

Comment: @ChrisDixon I thinking that maybe there is small jquery plugin that just do that. I don't want huge library.

Comment: jQuery is applicable, but not that straight forward. I am not sure how cross-browser solutions these are: http://www.ryantetek.com/2010/02/selecting-text-inside-html-elements-with-jquery/,  http://coderzone.org/library/Select-text-in-a-DIV-SPAN-or-table-cell_1047.htm. Highlighting a selection with JavaScript: http://tech.pro/tutorial/1075/javascript-highlighting-selected-text

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to modify the document selection in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075304/how-to-modify-the-document-selection-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With help from @ADNow in comment I was able to write jQuery plugin that select the text, I've removed $.browser so it work for jQuery >1.9.

```
$.fn.sel = function() {
    var node = this[0];
    if (document.body.createTextRange) {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(node);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        if (selection.setBaseAndExtent) {
            selection.setBaseAndExtent(node, 0, node, 1);
        } else if (document.createRange) {
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(node);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this in a small library, smaller than jQuery, then you can use the Sizzle engine (what jQuery selectors is built from). This is only 4K in size when minified.

http://sizzlejs.com/

Comment: I don't want to select element but text like in Word process when you want to change style of selected text.

Comment: This contradicts your question

Comment: @ADNow no, I want to select text not DOM Node.

Comment: Ahhh, then that's completely different then! Potentially the question needs changing a tad :)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML
```

or hook the element by a class or by an id. In this case i used the array of the p tags, and 0 for the first element

Comment: I don't want to get the text I want to select it like you do when you click and drag.

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood you. Here's an old topic about what are you looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128130/select-text-in-javascript